# Spring boot mybatis with stored procedures sybase

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, sybase, mybatis

I am working on a spring boot application which queries Sybase ASE.
I am using
- Hikari Datasource
- spring-boot mybatis 2.1.0

In my application, I have several select queries and execute a stored procedure. After looking at the log, I noticed that the application creates a new session and closes it for every single SQL.
To manage it, I tried using @Transactional annotation. I could see that the application no longer creates sessions for each SQL, and it rather fetches and releases an existing session.

However, I could not execute the stored procedure. It complains as below:

*Stored procedure 'SP_111IN' may be run only in unchained transaction mode. The 'SET CHAINED OFF' command will cause the current session to use unchained transaction mode.*

I do not want it to chained off or not set it to be run in 'anymode'. I am afraid of any side effects.

Will there be any way I can fetch and release the one session without this issue?
I think there will be a setting for SqlSessionFactory, but cannot find.
Any help will be appreciated!

Summary :
I would like to keep one DB session, but cannot run Sybase stored procedures with @Transactional annotation.

Comment: Can you please paste the code

Comment: :( code is not accessible...